# When Does A Function Compile Code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a weird scenario. I was updating a shared file in the portal last week. The function seemed to a little laggy but compiling successfully. A week later, with my team not editing, the function starts to throw compilation errors. So the question is at what point does the function compile and pull shared folders? Could the lag cause it not to reload this file for a week?

```
#load "../Shared/SomeSharedFile.csx"
```

Just trying to see if anything other than someone going in and editing the file cause this to start failing.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It can take up to a minute to see compilation errors in the portal, IME. I always run my functions after updating the code to check for errors. I build in debugging logic so I can run the function without modifying resources.

Comment: @DanWilson I do the same I ran the function everything compiled just fine. I ran it a few times. Just seems weird that it would take a week for it to start erroring out.

Comment: @garfbradaz They were syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function compilation occurs when changes are made to the source and when new instances are brought up (as a result of an initial startup or scaling), but if there's a valid compilation error happening, that should only happen as a result of a file modification.